# based on argument type, only matching object of container will be called

Tags: c++, generics

all,
I have a container of objects, e.g.,

```
class ShapeBase {};
class Rect: public Shape {
void set(class Diag diag);
};
class Circle: public Shape {
void set(class Radi radi);
};
```

now I have an application class to call this list of shapes. My intention is that
the element of the list will only be called based on argument type.

something like this.

```
 class application {
    typedef std::list<ShapeBase*> List;
    List shapeList; 

    void set(class ???) {
    for (List::iterator it = shapeList.begin(); it != shapeList.end(); ++it)
    {
        // with in the loop of all objects in list,
        // only object with matching argument will be called  
        set(class ???);
    };
```

so that the application class has no idea of concrete shape at all.

How to do that in C++?

Comment: Are you talking about function overloading? Like `set(const ClassA &arg)` and `set(const ClassB &arg)`?

Comment: not really. I would like the application find the relevent shape through the iteration, then trigger right shape to do that.

Comment: In C++ it is not idiomatic to write `void set(class Radi radi);`, instead we just write `void set(Radi radi);` ... you shouldn't care if `Radi` is a class or a typedef for a class or a scalar type, just call it `Radi`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to do with a list of objects is fairly difficult with the definitions as you've set them up. A problem with the settup is that there's no association of `Rect` to `Diag` at compile time, so you have to tell the compiler that Rectangles expect specific constructor arguments. One solution is to template the `application::set` method and then specialize that template for each Shape.

Below is some pseudo-code to do that (no guarantees on compiling):

```
template<typename ShapeType>
void fillShapeTypeList(std::list<ShapeType*> fillList) {
    for (List::iterator it = this.shapeList.begin(); 
              it != this.shapeList.end(); ++it) {
        if (ShapeType *shape = dynamic_cast<ShapeType>(*it)) {
            fillList.push_back(shape);
        }
    }
}

template<typename ShapeType, typename ShapeSetter>
void set(ShapeSetter setter) {
    std::list<ShapeType*> fillList;
    fillShapeTypeList(fillList);
    for (std::list<ShapeType*>::iterator it = this.shapeList.begin(); 
             it != this.shapeList.end(); ++it) {
        (*it)->set(setter);
    }
}

void set(Diag setter) {
    set<Rect, Diag>(setter);
}

void set(Radi setter) {
    set<Circle, Radi>(setter);
}
```

There is another much, much more complicated way to get this to work without the `Rect`/`Circle` specific setters using 'Substitution Failure is not an Error' patterns -- but it's not worth the effort for this case.

In general you should ask yourself if you're doing the right thing when it's not obvious how to make the compiler do what you want. In this case you might be better off registering call backs for objects with an application or make all shapes of a specified type look at a central object for sizing information.